# Phpmyadmin is not opening in wamp server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

> Cannot load mysqli extension. Please check your PHP configuration

I have already remove; from the line ;extension=php_mysqli.dll
 in php.ini file . Still, nothing has been changed.

nothing change has been showing me.

Even i have reinstall wamp , restrat laptop as well.

Does any updation in a laptop can cause this? because yesterday i have updated.

Comment: Check error log and share here, then we can help .

Comment: check if php_mysqli.dll is inside php/ext folder

Comment: yes , php_mysqli.dll is there

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are trying to load mysqli extension to your local server.

Follow these steps.

1) Create file called `phpinfo.php` in `c:\wamp\www` and paste the following code in it.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

2) Run the file in browser i.e `localhost/phpinfo.php` you will be getting complete configurations that your server has.

3) Go to php.ini file in your server and remove `;extension=php_mysqli.dll` semicolon and save the file.

4) Restart WAMP server and PhpMyAdmin try to load `localhost/phpmyadmin`.

Hope this helps...!